# My program gets stuck/block in "in.readObject()" even with flush()

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, flush

I'm trying to implement a chat using Java with multi-thread client and server (being that the server is running 2 threads/client, 1 to receive and 1 to send) and right now I'm having a problem where the client gets stuck while doing `in.readObject();`.
I've searched and most answers were due to lack of `flush()` as `in` would block, however I've inserted a `flush()` everywhere that sends a message, and even after initializing the streams. I know for a fact I'm sending a message, however the client doesn't seem to be receiving it.
The client is using only 1 thread to receive and send.
The client is currently getting stuck in `run()` method in the following line.

```
obj = in.readObject();
```

Here's the Client code. (Sorry for the mixed languages)

```
public Cliente(JTextArea panel, String Utilizador, String destinatario,String title){
    super();
    this.panel = panel;
    this.Utilizador = Utilizador;
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
    this.title = title;

    try {
        cliente = new Socket(host,porto);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void run() {
    System.out.println("Inside RUN! (Receiving) - Cliente");

        System.out.println("in variable declared - Cliente");
        //escuta as mensagens do servidor e mostra no painel
        while(true){
            Object obj;
            try{
            //----------------------------------------------
            System.out.println("Last sentence. RIP");
            obj = in.readObject(); // MUDAR MUDAR MUDAR MUDAR MUDAR MUDAR MUDAR  MUDAR MUDAR  MUDAR MUDAR  MUDAR MUDAR
            System.out.println("Recebido um objecto - Cliente");
            if(obj instanceof Message){
                String mensagem;
                mensagem = ((Message) obj).getMessage();
                mensagem += "\n";
                panel.append(mensagem+"\n");
                GuardarConversa();
            }       
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//envia mensagens ao servidor
public void enviarMsg(Message msg){
    try {
        System.out.println("A Enviar msg! - Client.java");
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's the server class, just the sender. Which seems to be sending the message.

```
private void EnviarMensagem(){

    //EnviarListaContactos();

    while(true){
            Message msg;
            if(MessageQueue.getMessage().getDestiny().equals(MyName)){

                System.out.println("Encontrada uma mensagem na fila - EnviarDados");

                msg = MessageQueue.getMessage();
                try {
                    System.out.println("A enviar mensagem para o cliente - Enviar Dados");
                    out.writeObject(msg);
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println("Mensagem enviada - Enviar Dados");
                    System.out.println("Out="+out);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MessageQueue.removeMessage(msg);                    
            }
        }
}
```

I know it's a common question, but the common solution doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`readObject()` will block while there isn't an object or end of stream or an exception available. You have that in an infinite loop, which should terminate on `EOFException` or any `IOException` other than `SocketTimeoutException`, but it doesn't, so of course it's going to block, unless the peer is an endless source of instantaneous objects.

Comment: Yes that's all true, but I AM sending a message. I'm inserting it in the chat area and all the `print` suggest it's going through as all the sending part is being completed fully. Shouldn't it detect the `Object` being sent and handle it?

Comment: So there must have been an exception, or these two sockets aren't connected to each other.